# adding validations on a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add validations to just a specific page. 
right now I have a user put in their e-mail/pw/pw-confirmation when they sign up and after clicking submit it directs them to the users edit page.

I'm using the following line of code:

```
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :goals, uniqueness: true, on: :edit
```

unfortunately it's not validating can someone help me explain why ?

Comment: are you trying to validate whether :first_name, :last_name, date_of_birth, goals are empty or you are checking if these combination is unique

Comment: I want to validate if they're empty I also tried the following line of code :  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :goals, presence: true, on: :edit         but it didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to perform 'sexy validation' on multiple attributes at once. It won't work. try this instead:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :goals, on: :update
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you ! I added in presence instead of uniqueness (the error message is more to what I needed) but that's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is a bit misleading. Problem with your code wasn't the validation syntax. You can still use 
`validates :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :goals, uniqueness: true` but instead of `on: :edit` you should have `on: :update`